# Use SQL to Find Values Where its Many to One

Tags: sql, sql-server

The first part of my problem is not knowing how to correctly ask and phrase this question, so I apologize if this is a duplicate.

Aside from a users table, I have a table like this

```
[UserRoles]
UserID | RoleName
-------|---------
1      | Role1
1      | Role2
1      | Role3
1      | Role4
2      | Role1
2      | Role4
```

Another table like this:

```
[RoleRoleTypes]
RoleName | Function
-------------------
Role1    | FunctionA
Role2    | FunctionA
Role3    | FunctionB
Role4    | FunctionC
```

What I want to end up with is a table with the `UserID`, a comma separated list of roles, a comma separated list of functions.

End Result

```
UserId | Roles                       | Functions
-------|---------------------------- |------------------------------------
1      | Role1, Role2, Role3, Role4  | FunctionA, FunctionB, FunctionC 
2      | Role1, Role4                | FunctionC
```

The first two columns are rather easy, using stuff to create the comma seperated list of roles.   But I am unsure how to go about calculating a list of functions given that multiple roles make up a function.   A user must have all the roles listed to have the function.   So if you have role1, but not role 2, you don't have FunctionA.   I tried a variety of joins but never got anywhere close to the correct data.   Any advice?

Here is what I have for the first two columns

```
SELECT u.email, Roles = STUFF(
    (SELECT ',' + RoleName
    From UserRoles ur
    WHERE ur.UserID = u.UserID
    FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, '')
FROM Users u
```

*EDIT*   Added clarification and end result example

Comment: What do you mean "multiple rows make up a function".   If a user had Role1 but NOT Role2, would they, or would they not, have FunctionA?

Comment: Good question, they would need all the roles to make up a function.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simulating group\_concat MySQL function in Microsoft SQL Server 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/451415/simulating-group-concat-mysql-function-in-microsoft-sql-server-2005)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you just need to use similar approach as in the case of RoleNames and use `distinct` to avoid duplicate functions

```
SELECT u.userid, 
   Roles = STUFF(
     (SELECT ', ' + RoleName
      FROM UserRoles ur
      WHERE ur.UserID = u.UserID
      FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, ''), 
  Functions = STUFF(
     (SELECT distinct ', ' + rt.[function]
      FROM [UserRoles] ur
      JOIN [RoleRoleTypes] rt ON ur.RoleName = rt.RoleName 
      WHERE ur.UserID = u.UserID
      FOR XML PATH('')
     ), 1, 1, '')
FROM [User] u
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0d1c5/11)

Comment: This, unfortunately, did not work :(   The distinct keyword seemed to have no effect on the result.

Comment: @TaylorAckley I have updated the answer and created a demo. I feel that should be a correct answer. Please point out the demo inaccuracy if there is any.

Answer (score 0):

You are required to use the **Distinct** keyword in your query to avoid duplicacy of results.